# Limit of a reccurence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to find the limit of $a_n$ when n reaches infinity

$a_1=2014$

$a_n+_1=\sqrt[3]{(260a_n+1919)}$

Comment: Welcome to Math SE ! People here are willing to help ... providing you show your efforts. Explain what you tried and tell where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ has limit, say $A$, then let $n\to \infty$, we have

$$A^3=260A+1919.$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I can solve that,but I think I have to first prove that a_n is convergent and I don't know how to do that.And also I want to ask if the problem can be solved with the recursion tree?